# Azure Durable Function app with Postgres data store

Tags: postgresql, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

We need to host existing Azure Durable Function app outside of Azure. We can run the function app as a container, but we'll need to configure an alternate data store (which is currently using Azure Storage). I can see MS SQL is a supported alternate - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-storage-providers) - and this *will* work for us, but Postgres is more aligned with the direction we're headed, so would be preferable. Has anyone used Postgres as the storage provider for Azure Durable Function apps?

Answer (score 0):

The language specific operations to deploy outside the azure can be performed by the steps mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=python

For the storage considerations refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations

But there are no specific and perfect procedures for Postgre SQL and waiting for update from Azure.